# Undo COPY command redshift | Delete from redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have inserted data into a redshift table using a copy command. Unfortunately I passed a wrong file and now I want to undo that.
Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: load that exact same file to a different table, then delete from your main table using the different table as a lookup.

Comment: Careful.  There might be existing duplicate records.  If there are say two existing records "dog", and three new records also "dog", you only want to delete three records of "dog", not *all* records of "dog".

Comment: Sadly, there's almost a way you could do it.  Your new records may well all have the same insert MVCC generation, in the system column which records the insert generation.  Postgres lets you look at the system columns, so you could have figured out the generation and deleted only those records.  Redshift, alas, IIRC, does not let you access those columns.

Comment: BTW, the general solution to this is to pre-process your files so they have a column which is their filename.

Comment: @JonScott I have loaded the same file to a new table. I am now trying to delete using the following command : `DELETE FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id` but not working as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you describe what exacly is behaviour of delete statement? I would suggest first create select statement which returns rows you are trying to delete.